# Inkscape: How to have a Connector Line be two colors

Tags: color, vector, inkscape

I'm trying to connect two objects Filled with different colors with the Connector Tool, then have the Connector Line show the two different colors associated with the objects.  Can I do that with the Stroke of the Connector Line?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A possible work around would be to apply a linear gradient to the stroke, sampling both objects' fill colours for each end stop of the gradient. However the gradient won't move automatically with the diagram connector. You'd need to reposition the gradient each time you moved the objects.

Example

[image]

Comment: That's helpful, but pretty cumbersome when I have hundreds of nodes that I need to shift occasionally.  Is it possible for the Connector Line to be striped with those two colors and not a gradient?

Comment: Yes, it's cumbersome, that's why I added the "However" part to my answer. You could do [stripes with a gradient](https://imgur.com/DeIbH6x), but you'd still be in the same boat. The gradient will not move with a live connector.  As far as I know, there's no other way to get a single path live connector with two coloured strokes.

Comment: Of course if you remove the requirement for doing this with Diagram Connectors there are other ways to have two strokes, but that would likely require two paths with two different strokes. This is not possible with Diagram Connectors which are made of a single path only.

Comment: How would I accomplish the striped line if it weren't a Connector?

Comment: Perhaps just have two strokes side by side.  Each time you move an object however, you will then have to reposition the end nodes of each stroke attaching them. Obviously this is just as cumbersome. There's no magic trick here. Unfortunately the limitation is down to the nature of the SVG format where one path can only have one stroke.

Comment: Gotcha.  Can you step me through how to have stripes with a gradient like in your picture?  And also how to do it with simple lines?  I'd like to see which is easier.

Comment: @Phoenix Apply a linear gradient to the stroke, then using the Gradient tool, double click on the gradient to add two additional stops in the middle of the gradient, set them to the same colour and opacity as the two end stops, them move them both together into the middle. [See example](https://imgur.com/EnQpx2C)

Comment: @Phoenix Another example with [two strokes side by side](https://imgur.com/a/1zMvafW). The strokes are under the two circles. Couldn't be simpler really.

Comment: That looks good, but honestly I don't know how to do that.  Can you help me?

Comment: @Phoenix I just drew a straight line with the Bézier tool (pen tool), copied and pasted it, and placed them side by side, each with a different stroke applied.  Then send both to the bottom of the stack using the [End] key (Send to bottom).  There are no tricks here, this is all basic manual stuff.

Comment: Thank you.  Anyone else want to take a shot at this?